# Calling object prototype from another object's prototype

Tags: javascript, object

Probably obvious, but still confusing me.

Is it in anyway possible to call from an another object's prototype a prototype inside another object?

**Current set:**

```
function obj1() {
    this.myVar = 1;
}

obj1.prototype.helloWorld = function() {
    alert("Hello world!");
}

function obj2() {
   this.myVar = 2;
}

obj2.prototype.nonSense = function() {
    console.log(this.myVar);
}
```

**1.** Can `Obj2` prototype `nonSense` somehow call the prototype `helloWorld` in `Obj1`?** 
**2.** Can `Obj2` prototype `nonSense` somehow access the `Obj1` variable `myVar`?

Comment: I don't follow what you're trying to do... you can call the `helloWorld` method from anywhere with `obj1.prototype.helloWorld()`.

Comment: That actually solves the first problem. For some reason my mind rejected to think the word 'prototype' as part of the name while calling. I was almost certain it's something as simple as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're trying to do but you can call the `helloWorld` method directly:

```
obj1.prototype.helloWorld();
```

If you have an *instance* of `obj1`, you can get rid of the `prototype`:

```
var myObj1 = new obj1();
myObj1.helloWorld();
```

To access `myVar` from outside of `obj1` you will need to have called `obj1` - `myVar` won't exist until you have called the function in which it is declared. Most likely, you will want to create an instance of `obj1` by calling it with the `new` operator, as shown above. You can then access `myVar` just like any other property:

```
console.log(myObj1.myVar);
```